# Rootless-ly Running Docker Daemon inside another Docker container

Tags: docker, aws-fargate, docker-in-docker

According to Docker official website: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ it's possible to run Docker Daemon rootless-ly (without root access, no --privileged flag).

However I'm convinced this would not work when running from inside a Docker container. There is no way of getting `modprobe` inside a Docker container without root access (--privileged). So it's not possible to install the Docker rootless script.

Supposedly there is an official image in Docker hub: `docker:dind-rootless` image [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/25c81c65fe4e971ff75e67df38e8b9970b523f6e/19.03/dind-rootless/Dockerfile) So I pulled the image and SSH'd into the container, however I'm getting the following error when running `dockerd`

`INFO[2020-07-17T20:50:32.355617100Z] Starting up dockerd needs to be started with root. To see how to run dockerd in rootless mode with unprivileged user, see the documentation`

Any suggestions on how to run Docker daemon rootlessly inside another Docker container? I know this is possible with root, but is there a way to do without? I can't get root access as I'm deploying to AWS fargate, which doesn't support privileged access at the container level.

Comment: have you tried SSH as rootless?

Comment: Running `docker run -it --user rootless docker:dind-rootless /bin/sh` and then running `dockerd` yields the same results. 

`dockerd needs to be started with root. To see how to run dockerd in rootless mode with unprivileged user, see the documentation`

`whoami` returns `rootless` which is the default user when you pull the `docker:dind-rootless` image

Comment: This doesn't satisfy your requirements, since it uses `--privileged`, but the PR which created the dind-rootless image also has an example of how to work with it: https://github.com/docker-library/docker/pull/174#issuecomment-517036465

Comment: @NickODell .. that tripped my expectation as I thought the rootless option would remove that need. I guess it was still meant to run as privileged but not with root as user. This somewhat messes up your Fargate plan piratepete

Comment: Looks like a fundamental limitation - you are right guys, dind-rootless still requires `--privileged` flag, because of that dind-rootless isn't going to work with Fargate. 

Maybe AWS could provide some advise?

Comment: Ran into same issue, @piratepete did you get anything from AWS on this?

Answer (score 2):

It's been 2 years. There's an image for it now.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#rootless-docker-in-docker

Comment: According to the page you linked, the image still needs to be run with `--privileged`, though.